# Aligning the icon just below the div element

Tags: html, css

I have a div element and inside that I have an icon. I want to place the icon just below the value of the div element but it gets aligned to it horizontally on the same row:

[image: screenshot]

```css
.time {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: green;
  line-height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="time" style="vertical-align: middle"
 [style.color]="started ? 'green' : 'red'">
  {{formatTime(time)}}
  <i class="play icon"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you already tried? Displaying the icon element as a *block* element should be enough, e.g: `.icon { display: block; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the ***Flexbox***:

```css
.time {
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline, that's why you need to change its direction */
  flex-direction: column; /* now stacked vertically */
  justify-content: center; /*  centers them vertically */
  align-items: center; /* and horizontally */
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: green;
  /* not necessary
  line-height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  */
  margin: auto;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="time" [style.color]="started ? 'green' : 'red'">
  {{formatTime(time)}}
  <i class="play icon">&#9658;</i>
</div>
```